# JUnit 4 with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing, junit3

Is possible I use JUnit 4 with my class extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`?

I am getting the following warn:

> @Test inside class extending JUnit3 TestCase

My class

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is possible I use JUnit 4 with my class extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Yes, though you have to follow [the documented recipe](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide) (see the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` instructions part-way down the page).

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4) contains an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` that follows the recipe.

> I am getting the following warn

Yes, that's [an IDEA warning that should be fixed in an upcoming release of Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=99021).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Android JUnit is JUnit3.  Tests are method whose name begins with "test"

Comment: `AndroidJUnitRunner` offers support for JUnit4, with specific instructions for getting `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` working. It's a trifle clunky and triggers the IDEA warning mentioned in the question, but it works.

Comment: I'll be darned!  Voting myself down.